# How to mute audio thread of another application or change max volume of another application?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

Please, help me solve the next issue - How can I get access to audio playback of another application(s)?
It is possible situation when two apps are playing audio content, e.g. some game and radio app. How to get access to stream of one of them to mute it?
Or maybe there is a way to adjust volume setting of one of the Apps on the fly.
I can't find anything like it in android SDK.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure about this but you can send a broadcast message from one app to another. so you should be able to act upon it like send a broadcast (turn volume down) and when the other app receives it it do just that -- more here -- http://hmkcode.com/android-sending-receiving-custom-broadcasts/

Comment: Apps do not have volume settings. Devices have volume settings. If you wish to take over control over the audio, use the audio focus APIs.